# What is the way of scrolling left inside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have a Panel component with an `overflow-x: scroll;`.

It has a lot of data and I want to be able to scroll horizontally inside of it.

What would be the way of doing it?

Does setting the `ref`'s `element.scrollRight` 'DOM-way' is the recommended way of doing it?

**Code example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/31rzwl8r25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it, its `scrollLeft`, https://codesandbox.io/s/r075r6mrmn

I guess, as pixels count starts from left to right, there is only `scrollLeft` function. Start scrolling from left (0 to 100% of width) to the right

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

```
scrollRight = () => {
    if (this.text) {
      console.log("clicked...", this.text.current.scrollLeft); // 0
      this.text.current.scrollLeft = 200;
      console.log("clicked...", this.text.current.scrollLeft); // 200
    }
};
```